# Datables not displaying properly with a table created in javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a table

```
<table class="display" id="tbl">
            </table>
```

Using javascript I've created a string data and then used

```
$('#tbl').append(data);
```

Afterward I am using

```
$('#tbl').DataTable();
```

To make the table a datatable.

All of the html for the table is correct. It does some formatting on the table, but it looks different and there is no pagination or ability to show a certain amount of entries.

I'm getting these errors in the console:

```
    jQuery.Deferred exception: e[i] is undefined X@https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:66:150
wa@https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:70:284
e@https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:91:115
n/<@https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:93:118
each@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:2813
each@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:1001
n@https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:83:194
h.fn.DataTable@https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:165:488
@file:///Users/Samprit/Documents/jsontable/employees.html:86:23
j@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:29566
g/</k<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:29882
undefined
```

&

```
TypeError: e[i] is undefined
```

Comment: Is the document ready by that time that is done?  [see this](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this `$('#tbl').append(data);` before calling `$('#tbl').DataTable();`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue.

```
$('#tbl').DataTable();
```

Has to be done after the table is loaded. So added to a function and called the function, this solved the issue.